# Change active tab using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 tabs on my page (using Bootstrap):

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li> 
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div> 
</div>
```

When I send a POST request from the profile tab, I want to make this tab active, how can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you have an "active" class to make a tab active. In this case, you can just do:

```
$("#home").removeClass("active");  // this deactivates the home tab
$("#profile").addClass("active");  // this activates the profile tab
```

Answer (score 8):

Your exact example is in the documentation, and it says that to activate a tab you do :

```
$('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show')
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li <?php if empty($_POST): ?> class="active" <?php endif; ?> ><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" <?php if !empty($_POST): ?> class="active" <?php endif; ?>>Profile</a></li> 
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane <?php if empty($_POST): ?> active <?php endif; ?>" id="home">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane <?php if !empty($_POST): ?> class="active" <?php endif; ?>" id="profile">...</div> 
</div>
```